# UILabel skeleton not showing while it's inside a stack view

Tags: ios, swift

Simply, I'm trying to display the skeleton for two UILabels that are subviews of a stack view. When I'm saying `label.isSkeletonable = true` it doesn't work at all. However, when I make the stack view `isSkeletonable = true` it works and becomes like the picture below
[image]

```
class ArticleCellView: UITableViewCell {
// MARK: - *** Properties ***
static let cellIdentifier = "ArticleTableViewCell"

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.isSkeletonable = true
    contentView.isSkeletonable = true
    configure()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

// MARK: - *** UI Elements ***
lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textAlignment = .natural
    label.textColor = UIColor(named: "AccentColor")
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0, weight: .medium)
    label.isSkeletonable = true
    
    return label
}()

lazy var abstractLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.textAlignment = .natural
    label.textColor = UIColor(named: "AccentColor")
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
    label.isSkeletonable = true

    return label
}()

lazy var thumbnailImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.frame.size.width = 100
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.isSkeletonable = true

    return imageView
}()

lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView()
    stack.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    stack.distribution = .fillEqually
    stack.spacing = 20
    stack.isSkeletonable = true

    return stack
}()

func configure() {
    // Adding subviews
    contentView.addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
    contentView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    stackView.addSubview(abstractLabel)
    
    // Setting up the constraints
    thumbnailImageView.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
        $0.width.height.equalTo(100)
        $0.centerY.equalToSuperview()
    }
    
    stackView.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.leading.equalTo(thumbnailImageView.snp.trailing).offset(10)
        $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
        $0.top.bottom.equalTo(thumbnailImageView)
    }
    
    titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
        $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(2)
        $0.top.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
    }
    
    abstractLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
        $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(2)
        $0.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom).offset(10)
        $0.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(2)
    }
    
}
```

}

As far as you can tell, no other solution out there worked for me even clipsToBounds did nothing. I'm using the SkeletonView from the following: https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView

Comment: What is `isSkeletonable` ? That's not from UIKit.

Comment: @HangarRash Sorry, I edited the question with library I'm using. I think it's a well-known one for iOS.

Comment: @AhmedAlFailakawi - start simple... put a label on a view controller and see if `.isSkeletonable = true` works. If it does, add another label, constrained to the first, and see if it works for both. If it does, embed the labels in a stack view and see if it works. If it does, then start to look at why it wouldn't be working in your cell. If it doesn't work, then get it to work before trying to use a cell.

Comment: @AhmedAlFailakawi - As a side note, this may be part of what's not working. Your code is adding `titleLabel` and `abstractLabel` to a stack view incorrectly. You have `stackView.addSubview(titleLabel)` but it needs to be `stackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)` (same with `abstractLabel`). You're also adding leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints to those labels, which you shouldn't be doing. The stack view will ***arrange*** the labels (hence, `addArrangedSubview`).

Comment: @DonMag I agree that ```addArrangedSubview()``` did make a difference with the skeleton. However, eliminating the constraints for both labels missed up the text displayed after the skeleton.

Comment: @AhmedAlFailakawi - did you have success with the *"start simple"* steps I suggested? And what do you mean by *"messed up the text displayed"*? A **big** part of the problem trying to help you is that we must installKingFisher (I believe, based on this line `thumbnailImageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()`), and SnapKit, and SkeletonView. Then we have to guess at how you're setting up your data and tableview and implementing `cellForRowAt` etc, etc, etc. See if you can put together a [mre] so we can download and run your code directly.

Comment: @AhmedAlFailakawi - as another side note, you've told us *"it doesn't look right"* ... but you ***haven't*** told us how you **want** it to look. Is this close? https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a8Gw.png

Comment: @DonMag Yes, that's exactly how the layout should look like.

Comment: @DonMag The KingFisher line is not related to the problem at all since the layout is being messed up only for the labels, and KingFisher is only to download the image it's not related to UI or auto-layout.

Comment: @AhmedAlFailakawi - *"The KingFisher line is not related to the problem..."* -- I know. My point was, someone trying to help you has to either figure out what that is (and figure out it can be ignored), or has to also install KingFisher. When posting a question, you should try to make it ***as easy as possible*** for someone else to copy/paste your code and run it. I've posted an answer with some notes and a modified version of your cell class. You would help yourself greatly by spending some time learning the basics of auto-layout and constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add the labels as ***arranged*** subviews of the stack view.

So, this:

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(abstractLabel)
```

instead of this:

```
stackView.addSubview(titleLabel)
stackView.addSubview(abstractLabel)
```

Next, because you want the labels to be arranged Vertically, set the stack view axis (and spacing) accordingly:

```
stack.axis = .vertical
stack.spacing = 10
```

and, because we want the stack view to ***arrange*** the labels, don't set any constraints on the labels:

```
//  titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
//      $0.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
//      $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(2)
//      $0.top.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
//  }
//
//  abstractLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
//      $0.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
//      $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(2)
//      $0.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom).offset(10)
//      $0.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(2)
//  }
```

and finally, it is a **really good idea** to add comments so you understand what your code is trying to do:

```
// Setting up the constraints
thumbnailImageView.snp.makeConstraints {
    // image view leading is 10-points from superview (contentView) leading
    $0.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
    // 100 x 100
    $0.width.height.equalTo(100)
    // top and bottom constrained to top and bottom of superview (contenView)
    $0.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
}
    
stackView.snp.makeConstraints {
    // stackView leading is 10=points from image view trailing
    $0.leading.equalTo(thumbnailImageView.snp.trailing).offset(10)
    // 10-points from superview (contentView) trailing
    $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
    // stackView centered vertically to image view
    $0.centerY.equalTo(thumbnailImageView)
}
```

Here's the full, modified version of your cell class:

```
class ArticleCellView: UITableViewCell {
    // MARK: - *** Properties ***
    static let cellIdentifier = "ArticleTableViewCell"
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        // from the SkeletonView docs:
        //  SkeletonView is recursive, so if you want show the skeleton in all skeletonable views,
        //  you only need to call the show method in the main container view. For example, with UIViewControllers.
        // So, we only need to set it on self
        self.isSkeletonable = true
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // MARK: - *** UI Elements ***
    lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .natural
        label.textColor = UIColor(named: "AccentColor")
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0, weight: .medium)
        
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var abstractLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.textAlignment = .natural
        label.textColor = UIColor(named: "AccentColor")
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
        
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var thumbnailImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.frame.size.width = 100
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        return imageView
    }()
    
    lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        // we want Vertical Stack View
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 10
        
        return stack
    }()
    
    // MARK: - *** Methods ***
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        thumbnailImageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
        thumbnailImageView.image = nil
    }

    func configure() {
        
        // Adding subviews
        contentView.addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(abstractLabel)
        
        // Setting up the constraints
        thumbnailImageView.snp.makeConstraints {
            // leading is 10-points from superview (contentView) leading
            $0.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
            // 100 x 100
            $0.width.height.equalTo(100)
            // top and bottom constrained to top and bottom of superview (contenView)
            $0.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints {
            // stackView leading is 10=points from image view trailing
            $0.leading.equalTo(thumbnailImageView.snp.trailing).offset(10)
            // 10-points from superview (contentView) trailing
            $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
            // stackView centered vertically to image view
            $0.centerY.equalTo(thumbnailImageView)
        }
        
    }
}
```